# Running php files with xampp

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to run PHP file through localhost with xampp. I'm using VS Code as my text editor. I created a folder in htdocs but when I try to run the php files, it doesn't seem to work. I've been searching for help for a couple of days but I wasn't able to come across anything yet.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

php . If u want to test works or not, try this  or  Hellow World" ?> The problem lies in your script . if u want test your original script go create index.html and use your code immediately. Have fun coding !

Comment: hey your files is index.php . If u want to test works or not, try this <?php echo "Hello World."?> or <?php echo "<h1> Hellow World</h1>" ?> The problem lies in your script . if u want test your original script go create index.html and use your code immediately. Have fun coding !

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: His script to test is wrong. He is created file with name "index.php".  Then at index.php he is using code `<h1> Hi </h1>` only. You are can see from screen shoot above. Of course thats not going work or appear. At last he is should type `<?php  echo "<h1> Hi</h1>";?>`